# Material appearance in sculpt mode

Tags: materials, sculpting

I am novice in blender and in all guides i've seen for now never was explained how to apply materials in scuplt mode. So i have created material, applied it and it works fine in object mode, but in sculpt mode my scuplting remains white (default).
 That is i want to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **Matcap** instead. It is in *Properties menu*<kbd>N</kbd> under *Shading*.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Go to the *Options* tab of the *Tool Shelf* and check the ***Show Diffuse Color*** checkbox.
[image]

Comment: Off-topic, but how did you turn your screen capture in a gif animation?

Comment: See this topic to learn how to do it: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers